# Адаптивность Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, bootstrap

Я новичок в этом деле и не совсем понимаю как сделать адптивность на бутстрапе
**Покажите и подскажие пожалуйста как красиво адаптировать страничку.Совсем не заходит эта тема**

```js
var article_1 = {
    'foto': 'https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg',
    'title': 'Устаревшие языки, которые уже не стоит изучать',
    'intro': 'Есть много ЯП, которые уже отжили свое, но их все равно продолжают изучать. В этой статье мы расскажем про 5 языков, которые уже точно не стоит изучать, хотя многие до сих пор делают это.'
};

var article_2 = {
    'foto': 'https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg',
    'title': 'Зачем нужен язык программирования Rust?',
    'intro': 'Rust набирает популярность, но при этом многие до сих пор не понимают его ценности и функций. Мы расскажем про основные преимущества языка программирования Rust.'
};

var article_3 = {
    'foto': 'https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg',
    'title': 'Что выбрать C++ или C#? С чего лучше начать?',
    'intro': 'Между собой оба языка очень похожи. Статья поможет расставить всё по своим местам.'
};

var article_4 = {
    'foto': 'https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg',
    'title': '3 логические задачи для настоящего программиста',
    'intro': 'Компании любят проверять молодых специалистов на различные логические задачи. Мы подобрали три интересных задачи, которые заставят вас задуматься.'
};

var article_5 = {
    'foto': 'https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg',
    'title': 'Как создать свою криптовалюту?',
    'intro': 'Создание собственной криптовалюты это сложная задача, на которую уйдет не мало сил и времени. Мы расскажем вам общий алгоритм!'
};

var article_6 = {
    'foto': 'https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg',
    'title': 'ТОП 10: Подборка хобби для программиста',
    'intro': 'Мы подобрали 10 хороших хобби, чтобы можно было с удовольствием провести время вне работы, а также улучшить логические и креативные способности мозга.'
};

var article_7 = {
    'foto': 'https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg',
    'title': 'СЕО-продвижение – верный способ улучшить свой бизнес',
    'intro': 'Продвижение сайта это сложная работа, требующая вложений как денег, так и времени. Мы расскажем про верные способы СЕО-продвижения, позволяющие раскрутить сайт!'
};

var article_8 = {
    'foto': 'https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg',
    'title': '10 самых популярных сайтов написанных на Django',
    'intro': 'Django набирает популярность и многие крупные компании используют его для создания веб проектов. Мы подобрали 10 популярных сайтов, написанных на Django.'
};
    
var articles = [article_1, article_2, article_3, article_4, article_5, article_6, article_7, article_8];

var start = 0;

$("#loadMore").on("click", function () {
    var htmlToInsert = '';
    
    for(var i = start; i < articles.length; i++) {
        if(i > 3 + start)
            break;
        htmlToInsert += "<div class='card'><img src='" + articles[i].foto + "' class='card-img-top' alt='" + articles[i].title + "'><div class='card-body'><h5 class='card-title'>" + articles[i].title + "</h5><p class='card-text'>" + articles[i].intro + "</p><a href='#' class='btn btn-warning'>Читать далее</a></div></div>";
        
        if(i == articles.length - 1) {
            $("#loadMore").hide();
            break;
        }
    }
    $("#loadMoreBlock").append(htmlToInsert + "<div style='clear: both'></div>");
    
    start += 4;
});
// Форма поиска старт
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.popup-open').click(function() {
        $('.popup-fade').fadeIn();
        return false;
    }); 
    $('.popup-close').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.popup-fade').fadeOut();
        return false;
    });     
});
// Форма поиска конец
```

```css
body {
    background: #f1f1f1!important;
}
    
header {
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(74,74,74,.21);
}

header div .logo {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #a2252d;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

header div .logo:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

header span.logo_text {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Suez One',sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
}

header span.logo_text small {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: block;
    color: #9c3737;
}

header .navigation {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#search {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

header .btn {
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

.jumbotron {
    border: 2px solid #5f1012;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.articles h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #404040;
}

.card {
    width: 45%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float: left;
}

.blog-footer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 70px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.popup-fade {
    display: none;
}
.popup-fade:before {
    content: '';
    background: #c2c2c2;
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 2;
}
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: -450px;
    border-radius: 4px; 
    z-index: 10;    
}
.popup-close {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.popup p {
    font-size: 30px;
}

















/* @media screen and (max-wigth: 1200px) {
    .conrainer {
        width: 1140px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-wigth: 1199px) {
    .conrainer {
        width: 960px;
    }


}

@media screen and (max-wigth: 991px) {
    .conrainer {
        width: 720px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-wigth: 767px) {
    .conrainer {
        width: 540px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-wigth: 575px) {
    .conrainer {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Веб блог</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="container p-3 mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg" class="logo" alt="Лого сайта">
                <span class="logo_text">blablabla <small>bla</small></span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3 offset-1 text-right popup-open navbarSupportedContent">
                <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск">
            </div>

            <div class="popup-fade">
                <div class="popup">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Поиск</button>
                    <p class="text-danger"><b>Форма поиска</b></p>
                    <input type="search" id="search2" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger popup-close">Закрыть</button>
                </div>      
            </div>

            <div class="col-4 navigation text-right navbarSupportedContent">
                <a href="index.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Главная</button></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Статьи</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Контакты</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>
    <div style="background: #9a2f2d!important;" class="jumbotron container mt-5 p-3 p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 px-0">
                <h1 class="display-4">3 основные сферы применения языка Python</h1>
                <p class="lead my-3">До начала активного изучения любого языка программирования правильно было бы задуматься о сферах его применения. Мы расскажем про 3 самые популярные сферы применения языка Python.</p>
                <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-danger">Читать далее</button></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <h3>Новости</h3>
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Сравнение движков: Unreal Engine 4 против Unity 5</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Выбрать движок дело не простое, а особенно когда оба очень хороши. В статье мы проведем сравнение двух программ и выясним какой движок использовать именно Вам!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg" class="card-img-top">                  <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">7 девушек айтишниц из фильмов и сериалов</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Много ли вы знаете фильмов и сериалов, где главные персонажы это девушки программисты? Мы подобрали 7 фильмов с такой концепцией.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg" class="card-img-top">                  <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">11 полезных инструментов для веб-разработчика</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Разработчики постоянно пытаются сделать свою жизнь проще или расширить собственные возможности. Мы подготовили 11 инструментов, которые это обеспечат.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg" class="card-img-top">                  <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Что такое Deep Learning? Как работает глубокое обучение?</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Как работает глубокое обучение и что оно из себя представляет? В ходе статьи мы расскажем про Deep Learning и разберемся с его ключевыми понятиями.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
                <div id="loadMoreBlock"></div>
                
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="button" id="loadMore" class="btn btn-danger">Подгрузить больше</button>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 ">
                <h3>Анонсы</h3>
                <div class="p-3 mb-3 bg-light text-dark rounded">
                    Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.
                </div>
                
                <div class="p-3 mb-3 bg-info text-light rounded">
                    <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/600/depositphotos_2076527-stock-photo-help-red-button.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                    <br><br>
                    <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Читать далее</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <footer class="blog-footer container">
        <b>Все права защищены &copy;</b>
    </footer>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```